# Changing the installation of webservice

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, iis, biztalk

I have a Biz talk web-service. This webservice  is always installed  under C:\Inetpub\WWWRoot. But in production enviornment i want this to be installed in E:\Inetpub\WWWRoot (May be  even different one). How can i specify this in my service or some other  way, so that it is always installed in required  drive.

Thanks,

Jain

Answer (score 1):

In IIS you need to create a new WebSite which points at the new path (as opposed to the "Default Web Site" that points at C:\inetpub\wwwroot).  Then select this new website (instead of the "Default Web Site" in the setup of your web service.
--Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

Out of interest, you can also use the [WCF-Custom binding to directly host from BizTalk](http://www.biztalkgurus.com/blogs/biztalksyn/archive/2010/08/11/hosting-wcf-http-receive-location-inside-biztalk-without-using-iis.aspx) - this has the benefit of not having to worry about configuring the published IIS web service.